# How to display a number in app launcher icon in LG nexus devices (Badge)

Tags: android

I have already implemented Badger to display a number on app icon for Samsung devices.
Ref: https://github.com/shafty023/SamsungBadger
But I also want this for LG Nexus devices. I know that Samsung devices have custom App Launcher TouchWiz which provides the badge facility, but is there a work around to do this in LG nexus devices also?
As you may have seen notification counters for new messages on Messaging app icon and missed calls on Phone app icon, there could be a solution for this.

Comment: you can have widgets with image and text view to the top right corner

Comment: I think no. LG nexus devices is using default android launcher, which not provide such behavior. But you can make widget for home screen, which will looks like your app icon and have number in the corner. It will work on home screen, but not in application list. Therefore I don't like iOS patterns on Android.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think Android has reserved Badge feature for its system apps only.